# Linear Algebra: Vector Space Over a Field Operation Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, definition

I am confused how the operation $\cdot : F\times V\rightarrow V$ is defined for a vector space over a field. Is $\cdot : F\times V\rightarrow V$ simultaneously defined as $\cdot : F\times F\rightarrow F$ in regards to the field, or should there be symbols distinguishing the axioms below? Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I was to guess the operations are simultaneously defined, but I could be wrong.

***Definition 1:*** A [vector space over a field F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) is defined to be a set $V$. This set is said to have two operations $+: V\times V\rightarrow V$ and $\cdot: F\times V\rightarrow V$. Also, $V$ is defined to have the following conditions:

> $(C1)$ $V, +$ forms a commutative group with an identity element $=0$,
>
> $(C2)$ For all $a, b\in F$, for all $v\in V$, $(a⋅ b)⋅ v=a⋅ (b⋅ v)$,
>
> $(C3)$ For all $v\in V$, $1⋅v=v$,
>
> $(C4)$ For all $a\in F$, for all $u, v\in V$, $a⋅(u+v)=a⋅u+a⋅v$,
>
> $(C5)$ For all $a, b\in F$, for all $v\in F$, $(a+b)⋅v=a⋅v+b⋅v$.

---

***Definition 2:*** A $\textbf{field}$, $F$, is a set with two operations, $+$ and $\cdot$ which satisfies the following conditions:

> $(C1)$ $F, +$ forms a commutative group with an identity element $= 0$,
>
> $(C2)$ $F^{\neq  0}, \cdot$ forms a commutative group with an identity element $= 1$,
>
> $(C3)$ For every $a, b, c\in F$, $a\cdot (b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are **two** distinct operations, for which we use the same symbol. It is usually easy to distinguish between them: if we see $\lambda.v$, then

- if $\lambda\in F$ and $v\in V$, then we are talking about the function from $F\times V$ into $V$;
- if $\lambda,v\in F$, we are talking about the product defined in $F$.

Of course, if it turns out that $V=F$, there is space for ambiguity here, but in this case both operations are usually the same.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @W.G. If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Of course. You bet :)